# Sharing Vim Yank Register

Tags: vim, clipboard, buffer, yank

Is it possible to run multiple instances of Vim which share their yank registers? I'd like to avoid having to yank to the system clipboard with `"+y` or opening my files in split windows within the same Vim instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [Using vim/gvim with multiple...](https://superuser.com/questions/234708/using-vim-gvim-with-multiple-gui-windows/) Looks like it is on a todo list for the dev's

Answer (score 5):

In case the main thing you don't like about the `"+y` solution is the extra `"+` typing, here's how to make the default `y`/`d`/`p`/`c` register (the so-called "unnamed" register `""`) system-global:

`:set clipboard+=unnamed`

> When the "unnamed" string is included in the 'clipboard' option, the unnamed
>   register is the same as the "* register.  Thus you can yank to and paste the
>   selection without prepending "* to commands.

source: last paragraph of [`:help clipboard`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#clipboard)

Answer (score 1):

User gggg has posted a question that has received an answer which solves this problem via a shared text file and catching events via autocommands: [Make vim yankings global via a shared text file](https://superuser.com/questions/266547/rewriting-vims-yank)

Answer (score 0):

I made a plugin that does this.

https://github.com/ardagnir/united-front will have your vim instances automatically share most of their registers, including the default and yank registers. It works somewhat similarly to gggg's idea.