# Moving lines between split windows in vim

Tags: vim

I have two files, say `a.txt` and `b.txt`, in the same session of vim and I split the screen so I have file `a.txt` in the upper window and `b.txt` in the lower window.

I want to move lines here and there from `a.txt` to `b.txt`: I select a line with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, then I move to `b.txt` in  the lower window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>, paste with <kbd>p</kbd>, get back to `a.txt` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> and I can repeat the operation when I get to another line I want to move.

My question: is there a quicker way to say vim *"send the line I am on (or the test I selected) to the other window"*?

Comment: Use `q` macro? `q[some_letter] [whatever operations] q`, then call the macro with `[times to be called]@q`

Comment: I presume that you're deleting the line that you've selected in `a.txt`. If not, you'd be pasting something else into `b.txt`. If so, there's no need to select the line first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a good use case for a macro.  Macros are commands that can be recorded and stored in a Vim register. Each register is identified by a letter from a to z.

#### Recording

From [Recording keys for repeated jobs - Vim Tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip144)

> To start recording, press <kbd>q</kbd> in Normal mode followed by a letter (a to z). That starts recording keystrokes to the specified register. Vim displays *“recording”* in the status line. Type any Normal mode commands, or enter Insert mode and type text. To stop recording, again press <kbd>q</kbd> while in Normal mode.

For this particular macro, I chose the `m` (for move) register to store it.

I pressed <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to record the following commands:

- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete the current line (and save it to the default register)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to move to the window below
- <kbd>p</kbd> to paste the contents of the default register
- and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to return to the window above.

When I typed <kbd>q</kbd> to finish recording the macro, the contents of the `m` register were:

```
dd^Wjp^Wk
```

#### Usage

- To move the current line, simply type <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> in Normal mode.
- To repeat the macro on a different line, <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> can be used to execute the most recently used macro.
- To execute the macro 5 times (i.e., move the current line with the following four lines below it), use <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> or <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>.

Comment: I asked to see if there is a command unknown to me that does the job: it seems there is none. In absence of such a command, this can be a good solution.

Comment: @brad, you can find all the commands available to you in the documentation. If it's not there it doesn't exist… no need to ask random strangers.

Comment: @romainl, yes, I know this but vim documentation is really huge and, although it doesn't scare me, there is always the possibility to miss something. Moreover, it could also be that you can obtain the effect using the combination of 2 commands and in this case it would be hardly documented

Answer (score 0):

you can just go `:set clipboard+=unnamed` to use the system clipboard and that spans all vim splits.

I found this out over at this SO question
[Sharing Vim Yank Register](https://superuser.com/questions/237655/sharing-vim-yank-register)